# Can't Save Categories Magento 2.3.5-p1

Tags: magento2, category

So i cannot save categories and attempting to do so produces below error in system.log:

```
    [2021-04-15 16:16:30] main.CRITICAL: Error: Call to a member function getAttributeCode() on bool in /home/sites/buzzcateringsupplies.com/public_html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Observer/InvalidateCacheOnCategoryDesignChange.php:67
    Stack trace:
    #0 /home/sites/magento/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Event/Invoker/InvokerDefault.php(88): Magento\Catalog\Observer\InvalidateCacheOnCategoryDesignChange->execute(Object(Magento\Framework\Event\Observer))
    ...
    ...
```

Strange as seems to work in my dev environment so seems some update have not occured in live database when running setup upgrade. I notice that my custom layout update attribute is empty like below:

[image]

So i am assuming there are potentially a few things wrong here.

Other solutions suggest running queries like below in to database:

```
INSERT INTO `eav_attribute` (`entity_type_id`, `attribute_code`, `attribute_model`, `backend_model`, `backend_type`, `backend_table`, `frontend_model`, `frontend_input`, `frontend_label`, `frontend_class`, `source_model`, `is_required`, `is_user_defined`, `default_value`, `is_unique`, `note`) VALUES

(4, 'custom_layout_update_file', NULL, 'Magento\\Catalog\\Model\\Product\\Attribute\\Backend\\LayoutUpdate', 'varchar', NULL, NULL, 'select', 'Custom Layout Update', NULL, 'Magento\\Catalog\\Model\\Product\\Attribute\\Source\\LayoutUpdate', 0, 0, NULL, 0, NULL),
(3, 'custom_layout_update_file', NULL, 'Magento\\Catalog\\Model\\Category\\Attribute\\Backend\\LayoutUpdate', 'varchar', NULL, NULL, 'select', 'Custom Layout Update', NULL, 'Magento\\Catalog\\Model\\Category\\Attribute\\Source\\LayoutUpdate', 0, 0, NULL, 0, NULL);
```

However not a big fan and would like to get to bottom of why this update has not run. The above does actually allow saving of categories however the dropdown is still empty. I'm also confused as thought in 2.3.4 and above the Layout update XML field should no longer be present...

Have searched around and cannot see a solution or explanation and hoping someone might be able to point me in the right direction. Have tried a few DB imports and updates since however same thing happens.

Comment: It is normal for custom layout to appear empty like that in > 2.3.4 versions.

Comment: @Paj I think it is normal for it to say use existing or no update. The layout update xml is still present but not visible or update-able via admin i guess for security reasons but value still present for backward compatibility with existing setup.Certainly not normal for categories not to save however...

Comment: Yes category should of course save without error. You can add custom layouts manually to populate this dropdown using a catalog_category_view_selectable_XX_Test.xml layout file where XX is the ID of the category.

Comment: Also I think layout update xml textarea should be removed in 2.3.5. Did you upgrade recently? Are you sure your upgrade completed succesfully?

Comment: Yeah that is why i am concerned upgrade looked fine but i can see it didnt. Did it all again and it seemed to work, quite concerned still as to why this is happening as these are just test deployments at the moment.

Comment: Are you using redis for system cache? Always make sure redis has been fully flushed after upgrade (redis-cli flushall) as outdated cached data can cause problems.